# Is Toothless male or female?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In the movie *How to Train your Dragon*, the sex of the Night Fury Toothless is never mentioned (or I must have missed if it is).

In either case, is Toothless a male or a female, and why?

Comment: It could be a female because they have yet shown us another night fury to compare with.

Comment: I watched that christmas special and i swore hiccup said near the end "Toothless is a female?" I don't know can someone tell me im wrong

Comment: Yes Toothless is male.
In movie only it mentioned while Hiccup introducing toothless with Astrid

Comment: Toothless is male. SPOILER ALERT!! How to train your dragon 3 shows toothless with a female and kids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Novels

The [original novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Train_Your_Dragon) clearly indicate that he's male. Note that he's referred to as "he" by both the characters in the book *and* the omniscient narrator

> Hiccup decided to take the opportunity to check on Toothless's basket.
>   He pulled it out from under the bed. A thin plume of bluish gray smoke
>   was drifting out from under the lid.
>
> Fishlegs whistled. "**He's awake all right,**" said Fishlegs.

and

> "Oh shut up, Fishlegs," said Hiccup, impatiently, "you're frightening
>   it."
>
> Toothless huffed and puffed and blew out some smoke rings. **He inflated
>   his neck to make himself look bigger,** which is something dragons do
>   when they are scared or angry.

---

### Films

Where the films are concerned, we have both in and out-of-universe quotes that show that he's a male;

From HTTYD2's writer/director; [Dean DeBlois](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/behind-screen/annie-awards-how-train-your-768932)

> "I'm halfway through the script. It continues to track Hiccup's coming
>   of age, but it's also equally shared now that Hiccup and Toothless are
>   chiefs of their clans. The story also follows Toothless' storyline,
>   and I think audiences will like that because they seem to respond well
>   to **Toothless' antics and what seems to be going on in his head.**"

and from the original [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/How-to-Train-Your-Dragon.html) for HTTYD1

> Amazed, Hiccup sits up and tries to touch him. Toothless HISSES and
>   flaps off to a crash on the other side of the cove. **He BLASTS the
>   mossy ground** to a red-hot temperature... and curls up on it like a
>   giant dog.

Answer (score 6):

The [Wiki](http://howtotrainyourdragon.wikia.com/wiki/Toothless) mentions that he is male.

Plus the dragon is referred to as a 'he' by Hiccup several times in the movie as well as in the books by Cressida Cowell.

Comment: I agree... as far as we know, Hiccup seems to believe Toothless is male. I'm sure it's potentially a future movie/Netflix show concept to actually confirm or refute this but for now, we have to go with what Hiccup believes.

Comment: Note that fan wikis are secondary sources too, you would still need a primary source to prove your point.

Comment: `as well as in the books` - I would say that is a pretty definitive source